# EF 6 2x2 Foreign Keys from 2 tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, database-design, foreign-keys

I want to have tables `PaintballWorker`, `Invoices` and `Receipts` connected with relationships. `PaintballWorker` can have many `Invoices` and `AddedInvoices` as well as can have many `Receipts` and `AddedReceipts`. Relationship between `PaintballWorker` and `Invoices` works great with both `Invoices` and `AddedInvoices`. I wanted to do the same with `Receipts` but I'm getting error while updating database:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Receipts_dbo.PaintballWorkers_ReceiptAddedByID". The conflict
>   occurred in database "1028_test", table "dbo.PaintballWorkers", column
>   'PaintballWorkerID'.

My main class (`PaintballWorker`):

```
public class PaintballWorker : Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int PaintballWorkerID { get; set; }
        (other properties)
        [InverseProperty("PaintballWorker")]
        public virtual List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("InvoiceAddedBy")]
        public virtual List<Invoice> AddedInvoices { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("PaintballWorker")]
        public virtual List<Receipt> Receipts { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("ReceiptAddedBy")]
        public virtual List<Receipt> AddedReceipts { get; set; }
    }
```

My `Receipt` class:

```
public class Receipt
    {
        [Key]
        public int ReceiptID { get; set; }
         (other properties)
        public int PaintballWorkerID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PaintballWorkerID")]
        public virtual PaintballWorker PaintballWorker { get; set; }

        public int ReceiptAddedByID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ReceiptAddedByID")]
        public virtual PaintballWorker ReceiptAddedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

My `Invoice` class:

```
public class Invoice
    {
        [Key]
        public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
        (other properies)
        public int PaintballWorkerID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PaintballWorkerID")]
        public virtual PaintballWorker PaintballWorker { get; set; }

        public int InvoiceAddedByID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("InvoiceAddedByID")]
        public virtual PaintballWorker InvoiceAddedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

Can someone explain what is wrong here?

For now `public virtual PaintballWorker PaintballWorker { get; set; }` works fine from `Invoice` and `Receipt`, updated database with `public int InvoiceAddedByID { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("InvoiceAddedByID")]
            public virtual PaintballWorker InvoiceAddedBy { get; set; }`
and works fine aswell, but when I want to update database with
`public int ReceiptAddedByID { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("ReceiptAddedByID")]
            public virtual PaintballWorker ReceiptAddedBy { get; set; }`
I'm getting error which I wrote at the beginning.

Comment: Did you check if there is already a Foreign Key named "FK_dbo.Receipts_dbo.PaintballWorkers_ReceiptAddedByID" in your database ?

Comment: @Thibault there is only one foreign key `FK_dbo.Receipts_dbo.PaintballWorkers_PaintballWorkerID`

Comment: Do you already have data in these tables ?

Comment: `Invoices` table is empty, `Receipts` not, seems that was the problem. Well thank you, I didn't know that having records is a problem with updating database.

Comment: There was probably a value in the 'ReceiptAddedByID' column that contains an ID that is not available in the 'PaintballWorker' table. So SQL cannot create the foreign key.